# Dynamically shown thumbnails don't appear in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have the full code of this form [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xvnbe0d7/1/)

```
<form id="asd">
    <input type='file' name="filename[1]" id="1" onchange="add()"/>
    <img id="a1" src="" alt=""/>
</form>
```

which generates a new file input and a new image w/pending source, which is given after the file input recieved a selection.

This works on desktop, but, on mobile browsers it only shows the first image selected, the other ones just doesnt appear, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code does not work in desktop either. The root cause is: when add new `<img>` element (variable `newimg`), it results in a nested structure (`<img><br/><img src="..."></img>`), which will never display any images.

To fix this issue, the outside tag need to be changed to `<div>`.

A working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/xvnbe0d7/7/) is made. It works in mobile device too. Please check.